# Como puedo conservar el formato de mi texto en html?

Tags: html, textarea

Tengo un problema, sucede que tengo en mi base de datos un texto, ejemplo:

"What is Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."

Son varios parrafos y titulos como el del ejemplo de arriba seguidos.

Al llamar este texto desde la base datos, y ponerlo dentro de un div o una etiqueta p, todo el texto se junta, se pierden todos los saltos de linea, sin embargo, cuando lo pongo dentro de un textarea sí me conserva el formato, el problema es que eso no me sirve, alguien sabe como conservar el formato?

Gracias de ante mano!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haz lo siguiente:

1. Utiliza un elemento del tipo pre;
2. Agrega una clase a ese pre con este css;

   .testClass{
      white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, supported since 1999 */
       white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera */
       white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera */
       white-space: pre-wrap; /* CSS3 - Text module (Candidate Recommendation) http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#white-space */
       word-wrap: break-word; /* IE 5.5+ */
   }

Live Demo

```js
let lorem = `What is Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.`;

$('#getText').on('click',(e)=>{
let target = $('#test');
target.empty().append(`<pre class="testClass">${lorem}<pre>`);
})
```

```css
.testClass{
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, supported since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera */
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* CSS3 - Text module (Candidate Recommendation) http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#white-space */
    word-wrap: break-word; /* IE 5.5+ */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" style="width:500px">
  
</div>
<br>
<br>
<button id="getText">obtener texto</button>
```

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono perfecto!! :)